# Kotlin - Asynchronous functions in Kotlin

Tags: multithreading, kotlin, asynchronous

So, I have this problem:

```
fun doStuff(newUser: User) : ReturnType {

 --- little bit of things here --- 
 
 --- some AWS things
 --- some MongoDB insertions
 --- some Kafka things

 return user;
}
```

Here is the question, I need to make this kind of an async function. The aws, MongoDB and Kafka things should execute while I return the user, because I don't need the user info to do any of this tasks. Is there a way I can return the user, while I am still in the process of calling AWS, DB insertions etc..?

I've tried to take a look in Coroutines but I don't have an ideia on how to make this work.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following flow:
Create a parent function. Let's call it A

```
fun A() {
   asyncAWSFunction()
   asyncMongoDBInsertions()
   asyncKafkaThings()
   val user = createUserFunction(userInputs: xyz)
   return user
}
```

This will return the user and will do the additional stuff asynchronously.

Comment: Interesting, So my endpoint will return my user variable before all the AWS, Mongo and Kafka computing stuff, right? And how do I create async flow? @Prakul

Comment: Correct.
For async flows, you may use the `suspend` keyword. Read more about it https://kotlinlang.org/docs/async-programming.html#coroutines

Also, if you found the answer and comment useful feel free to upvote.